# How to run a specific rule for ng lint

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, eslint, typescript-eslint

**TLDR;
How to lint an Angular project for one rule type.**

I can't work out how to auto-fix linting issues that are outputted by `ng lint`.

For example an error such as this:

```
   7:16  error  Strings must use singlequote  @typescript-eslint/quotes
```

I expected to be able to run something like:

```
ng lint --fix-type @typescript-eslint/quotes
```

But that errors. These docs are not very useful: https://angular.io/cli/lint

Related dev dependencies:

```
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.17.0",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
```

Comment: Have you found an answer for this question?

Comment: No, not sure it's possible at the moment